Children scamming people trying to get quarters for the arcade
The short (from the late 70's or early 80's, I think) was about video game addiction and had children scamming people trying to get quarters for the arcade. I remember one kid claiming it was for "school supplies." I think it was from an episode of Saturday Night Live, but I'm not having any luck locating it. I'd love to see it again. It also had the memorable line about a kid making money "the hard way. A quarter at a time."

This was indeed from SNL, and was called "Allen: The Video Game Junkie".
The video is here, on Charleston Gameroom's Facebook page.

This is a 80s SNL skit that featured Allen: The video Game Junkie & Phillis the hooker who earns money the hard way...a quarter at a time!


Please add a description of the video and other pertinent information to your answer. That link might not be around forever.

One could argue that my question counts as a description of the video. I remembered it pretty well, just forgot the title. As of today, the video is still up and has been since August 25, 2009.

The video is still up. Thanks again, Will.
